# How to set minimum width for Ext.grid.Column?

Tags: extjs

is it possible to set the minimum width for an Ext.grid.Column? The column can be resized and "fixed" config is false. Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: When you say 'minimum width' you mean that you can't even resize below this width, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a config property of the grid called `minColumnWidth`. However, this will set a minimum for all columns, not just one specific column. In order to enforce a minimum width on specific columns, you'll likely need to extend or override some methods in [`Ext.grid.GridView`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridView)

Comment: can you please provide a working example, since this is marked as the accepted answer? I am looking to accomplish this as well.

Comment: Ext (since v4) has had a minWidth property on the column that will use the min width, or the auto-calculated width based on layout, as appropriate. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-minWidth

Answer (score 3):

The Grid column does not have a `minWidth` property.The `width` property does behave as a `minWith` when the `fixed` property is set to false. So, you will have to have your configured as such:

```
{
    header: 'Name (English)',
    dataIndex: 'name_en',
    sortable: true,
    width: 150
}
```

The `width` being set to 150 ensures that you have a width of 150 pixels. And since I do not have the `fixed` set to true, I will be able to expand the column width. If you remove the width property, the column will display with a width of largest data element for that column.

Comment: If napoleonit76 doesn't want it to resize below a minimum width, then this code is incorrect. See the [Array grid example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.html) in the ExtJS Examples.